# How to Change the URL without doing any Server Trip

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I want to change the URL (QueryString Data) after the Page gets Displayed.
How can i do it ?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to add queries to your URL? Like "www.example.com?data=value"

Comment: Actually i dont want my Page to get Refresh.
Is it possible ?

Comment: I don't think what you're trying to do can be done. Furthermore, I don't think you understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Actually my URL is like www.example.com?id=5, I want it to be www.example.com after it gets Loaded.

Comment: Sounds like you need to rethink your application design. Why not have it do the work at id=5, then save some kind of context cookie and then redirect to example.com and have example.com display its data based on the context cookie?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

Answer (score 7):

You can't. The only part of the `location` that can be changed without the browser requesting a new URL from the server is the hash (since that is local to the current document).

Answer (score -2):

The javascript object window.location have property href. So you can change it in JavaScript code in such way:

```
location.href = 'http://stackoverflow.com/'
```

Comment: "without doing any Server Trip" - that triggers a server trip.